# WordPress Error 500 Except Home and wp-admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I am facing a 500 error on all of my blog posts except home page, but I can still access wp-admin dashboard page. My WordPress is on subfolder (www.domain.com/magazine). This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /magazine/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /magazine/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The problems is solved when I change my Permalinks into default. But when I change it into Pretty Permalinks then the problem came up again.

The problems occured when I activated rest-api and then deactivated that plugins.

Answer (score 2):

About Rest-API plugins - they don't touch the .htaccess file.

Do you use any Cache plugin(if yes then try to deactivate they)?

To see why you get a 500 error you need to look at the error logs on your server. 
Depending on your account type these may or may not be available to you, but your hosting company will be able to see what's happening.

500 errors can frequently occur with incorrectly configured rewrite rules contained in your ".htaccess" files, so you should probably try removing those from your folders to see if it's the cause. Keep a backup of those files, of course, you might still need them.

- Re-save permalinks
- Check that your server allows overriding directives with .htaccess.
- Check that your server has mod_rewrite enabled

If it doesn't help try to disable all plugins and try the procedure again.

Comment: Thank you, I have done as you suggests. But the problems are still came up, mod_rewrite is still loaded and the server can override .htaccess when I re-save Permalinks.

Comment: Oke, solved now. I edited my .htaccess to `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` instead `RewriteRule . /magazine/index.php [L]`

Comment: Cool!)
The same as you had delete .htaccess)

Comment: I think on an ordinary WP site with subfolder, `RewriteRule . /magazine/index.php [L]` will not break the site. The main problem is because I am using ELB on AWS that redirect users to the IP on WP, so we need to configure with `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` without subfolder.